# transactionobserver not called when user has no payment method

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, skpaymenttransaction

My iap problem start with when a user has not a payment method. iaps working in sandbox (interrupted simluation too) and real world. But in real app (downloaded from appstore - i tested in ios 12 - iphone 6) if i have no payment method app warning me to add one. Then appstore app opens (my app goes background) and i enter all credit card features to buy. Everything goes well and appstore prompt me that you bought product. But after turning back to my app (taking it to foreground) nothing happens. I cant get any information about transaction. Even i add appdidbecomeactive observer to catch again unfinished transactions. Again nothing... Then i added unfinishedTransaction function in app start. if i terminate app and start again. It catches unfinishedtransaction and doing my codes. But users who has no payment method think that app didnt work and they ask money back. So they are right i am paying back or change database of them. How can i handle this problem? I can't even test it in sandbox. Everytime i am giving price to the apple to test. Please help me.

Comment: It sounds like your delegate (observer) method is incorrectly written. You are probably failing to finish the transaction correctly. But you did not show us that method, so who knows? It's okay to talk about code, but you also need to _show_ the code.

Comment: My delegate stays in mainViewController. Its not a singleton class. So i didnt start transactionobserver in appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (may be this is the problem. But i can't even try it in sandbox. compile app send store pay again and again again...). I assume that when app goes to appstore delegate throw a failed transaction. and after turning back to my app no new call happens. And dont know which code i have to show you to explain my problem.

Comment: "So i didnt start transactionobserver in appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (may be this is the problem" Yes, that is certainly a serious mistake. You _must_ configure your transaction observer as soon as the app launches, just in case the store needs to talk to you at launch time. However, the fact that you have an issue just going into the background and coming back to the foreground suggests that you also have written the observer method incorrectly.

Comment: Yeap. removing delegate from a viewcontroller and using as a class extansion and also adding  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions solve the problem i think. everthing works right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
otherViewcontroller
@objc func saveBtnTUI() { 
    mainVC.messageSN(subject: subjectTF.text!, explain: explainTV.text!) 
    }
```

i'm handling my database connection to open new draft in mainviewcontroller after that calling pay func...

```
import StoreKit
MainViewcontroller, SKPaymentTransactionObserver    
func pay() { 
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPayment(product: product)) SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self) 
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
            for transaction in transactions {
                ...
                case .purchased: complete(transaction: transaction); break
                case .failed: fail(transaction: transaction); break
                ...
    }
    }

    func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
            print("complete...")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.paymentID = transaction.transactionIdentifier!; self.paySN()}
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction);  SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
        }
         
        func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.view.viewWithTag(999)?.removeFromSuperview()}
            
            if let err = transaction.error as? SKError {
                if err.code != .paymentCancelled {
                    var mStr:String = "", statusStr:String = ""; print("fail", err.localizedDescription, err.code.self)
                    if err.code == .clientInvalid {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .cloudServicePermissionDenied {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .cloudServiceRevoked {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .paymentInvalid {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .paymentNotAllowed {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else if err.code == .storeProductNotAvailable {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    else {mStr = "..."; statusStr = "..."}
                    
                    if #available(iOS 12.2, *) {
                        if err.code == .invalidOfferIdentifier {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                        else if err.code == .invalidOfferPrice {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                        else if err.code == .invalidSignature {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                        else if err.code == .missingOfferParams {mStr = "..."; statusStr = mStr}
                    } else {
                        mStr = "..."; statusStr = "..."
                    }
                    
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ERROR", comment: ""), message: mStr, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let cancelA = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil); alert.addAction(cancelA)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.paymentStatusSN(status: "fail", message: statusStr)
                }
                else {print("..."); self.paymentStatusSN(status: "cancel", message: "...")}
            }
            else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("ERROR", comment: ""), message: "...", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let cancelA = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil); alert.addAction(cancelA)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.paymentStatusSN(status: "fail", message: "...")
            }
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction); SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
        }
```